# Azure Powershell ISE Execution query

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am using azure powershell ISE. I have a very long script to run where I am using variables to store data and further I am using them in my code. The problem is I am not able to run this script in a single go, reason being execution is not line by line. Sometimes it tries to execute a command before the variable is assigned its value. It throws an error.

I want to run 200 lines of code having 30 variables in a single go using powershell ISE. Eg. Problem is-

`Get-azurevm -servicename $a -vmname $b`

is getting executed before $a= xxx $b= yyy is getting initialized.I have initialized my variables before using but I guess execution fashion is not line by line.

What could be the possible solution for this?

Is there any option I can make the execution line by line ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can't you set breakpoints in the code?

Comment: I want to run 200 lines of code having 30 variables in a single go using powershell ISE. Eg. Problem is- Get-azurevm -servicename $a -vmname $b is getting executed before $a= xxx  $b= yyy is getting initialized.I have initialized my variables before using but I guess execution fashion is not line by line. Hope I am clear now

Comment: If you execute a PowerShell script it executes from top to bottom (no difference in the PowerShell ISE, if you use Run Script, not Run Selection), except you are using something like goto, if/else, try/catch etc. Also check that you are not declaring variables in script blocks. Outside of script blocks the variable would not exist. It's difficult to guess what the problem is without seeing the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure PS execution is always line by line. If something like this is happening you can break the code into function and you can execute your desired code to execute only if the before ones codes have already been executed. It is always good to go with modules if u have a long code.

Also you can use-

```
start-sleep -s "no. of seconds to give other code to execute"
```

for execution of code which takes a bit longer time.

Comment: I don't know how come this never hit my mind. This is really helpful I had completely forgotten about functions in powershell